# Referencing a static table without foreign key when persisting

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Let's say I have two entities (ommitted getters/setters):

```
@Entity
@Table
public class A {

    private Long id;
    private B b;
    private String details;

    @SequenceGenerator(name = "auto_gen", sequenceName = "a_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "auto_gen")
    @Column(name="id",updatable = false,nullable = false)
    @Id
    public Long getId(){return id;}

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
    public B getB(){
        return b;
    }

}


@Entity
@Table
public class B {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="gen",strategy = "BIdentityGenerator")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String reason;
    @Column
    private Boolean requiresDetails;
}
```

And the two tables are linked like so:

```
Table A
-------
id
b_id (foreign key to primary key in B)
details

Table B
-------
id
reason (unique)
```

Table B holds static data, so new rows should never be inserted.
Given I have a new object A and an entity relationship to an existing db object B, I would like to persist A as a new row and link to an existing row for table B. I would also like to persist A without having the id of B beforehand, only the unique `reason` value.

This scenario is fine if I manually provide an id for B before persisting A, but coding this way seems a bit cumbersome. I was wondering if there was a way to do it through a id generator to implicitly set the id of B given the value of `reason` in the database.
I have tried using GenericGenerator to generate the id (see below); however, this has the problem where it assumes the generated value is a completely new generated id and violates the primary key constraint. I have also considered using entity listeners, but documentations states that they shouldn't call `EntityManager`.

```
public class BIdentityGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {

    private static final String QUERY = "SELECT id FROM b WHERE reason = ?";
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BIdentityGenerator.class);

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object o) throws HibernateException {

        if (o instanceof B) {
            B b = (B) o;
            if (b.getReason() == null || b.getReason().isEmpty()) {
                throw new HibernateException("No reason provided.");
            }
            try {
                Connection connection = session.connection();
                PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(QUERY);
                statement.setString(1, b.getReason());
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
                if (resultSet.next()) {
                    long id = resultSet.getLong("id");
                    return id;
                } else {
                    throw new HibernateException(String.format("No row with reason %s exists.", b.getReason()));
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new HibernateException(String.format("Unable to retrieve reason %s", b),e);
            }
        } else {
            throw new HibernateException("BIdentityGenerator only supports B.");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the database setup you presented, this annotation:

> ```
> @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
> ```

is misspelled.  You appear to have meant `b_id`.

Later, you write:

> Table B holds static data, so new rows should never be inserted.

and I presume you mean also that existing rows should not be updated or deleted, either.  In that case, you should not be cascading *any* operations from entity `A` to entity `B`, which is the default if you do not specify.  That is, use simply this to map the relationship:

> ```
> @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
> @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
> ```

The main question seems to be this, however:

> This scenario is fine if I manually provide an id for B before
>   persisting A, but coding this way seems a bit cumbersome. I was
>   wondering if there was a way to do it through a id generator to
>   implicitly set the id of B given the value of `reason` in the database.

If by "provid[ing] an id for B" you mean *providing a B*, then that's exactly what you should do.  That is how entity relationships work in JPA: through entity instances (`myA.setB(someB)`).  If, on the other hand, you came up with some mechanism for setting `b_id` directly in table A, then yes, I can imagine that would be cumbersome.

In any case, no, you cannot use an ID generator for this.  In the first place, it's the wrong tool.  Those are intended and designed to provide unique IDs, and that's the very last thing you want.  In the second place, as I've already covered, you don't want to set the ID of a B, you want to set a B.

Since the collection of B entities is static, you should consider just loading *all* the Bs into memory at program startup, keeping them in an internal map, and drawing from those to assign Bs to your As.  It should not matter whether you allow them to become detached, as long as you turn off cascading from A to B.

Comment: Yes, you're correct that the join column was incorrect, I made a mistake when converting code to pseudocode. I agree with removing Cascading, it was left there to trigger the GenericIdentifier; I agree a proper solution shouldn't use it based on requirements.

I like your idea of loading B's into memory, I will probably use this as a solution. Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 0):

you should remove `CascadeType.ALL` from Entity A.
you should have DAO which returns you Entity B based on `reason`, something like `entityA.setEntityB(entityBDao.findBy(reason))`

Comment: Thanks, that's what I had implemented prior but wanted an implicit solution rather than having to explicitly link B to A.